# Grouping Instances/ Symbols Together

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, adobe

so I am working on a game where if you touch one side of a box, you'll be propelled in that direction.
* For example: Let's say I hit the *left* side of the box, I should be propelled *to* the left.

One way I could do this, is split the box into 4 instances where each instance is on the left, right, top & bottom sides. 
Is there a way for me to embed instances/ access parts of an instance, etc.

*OR* if there is a better way to do this can you tell me how?

Comment: Please review the question checklist: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @Atriace can you briefly explain what this question is missing from the checklist... it's a bit broad but I understand what OP is trying to do. Just want to know for my own curiosity.

Comment: @Kaushal: Although the question was mundane, he failed to demonstrate attempts (1) research, (2) explain what he's attempted already and (3) what code he's written to resolve the problem. From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.  It's a kindness to answer his question, but these kinds of questions are discouraged.

Comment: @Atriace, thanks that makes sense. To be fair to OP though, this is a common case between "doing it on the stage" and "doing it in code" that is somewhat unique to flash. His question was mainly about which direction hr should go, as opposed to a direct code question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just test the x and y position of the touch inside the the box when they touch it. Something like this pseudocode:

```
function onTouchDown(){
    if(touchX < halfBoxWidth)
    {
        // We touched the left side, so go left.
    }
    else
    {
        // We touched the right side, so go right.
    }
}
```

Comment: What about top and bottom? You could just copy and paste that with the Y coordinates, but then I would ALWAYS be going diagonally.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer to your question is yes; what you want to do is have a single container MovieClip with 4 internal MovieClips that will be your hit targets.

I would go for the following setup; i.e. use triangles.

```
------------
|\   top  /|
| \      / |
|  \    /  |
|   \  /  r|
|left\/   i|
|    /\   g|
|   /  \  h|
|  /    \ t|
| /      \ |
|/ bottom \|
------------
```

if you were to do it based on coordinates, as Adam Harte mentioned, handle it like a 9-slice grid. if you imagine the centre box oversized, that will give you maximum hit areas.

```
-----------------
|   |       |   |
|   |   T   |   |
-----------------
|   |       |   |
| L |       | R |
|   |       |   |
-----------------
|   |   B   |   |
|   |       |   |
-----------------
```